# SQL query to select average temperature for several records for each of the last 24hrs most efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table (sensor_temps) that stores temperatures taken every 5 minutes for hundreds of sensors:

```
id  |  mac_addr          |  temp  |  updated
--------------------------------------------------------
3   | 16:8C:DD:7B:DA:1B  |  76    |  2020-05-03 11:31:06
```

I have another table (sensors) that stores the details for each sensor:

```
id  |  mac_addr          |  IP                 |  location_id
--------------------------------------------------------------
43  | 16:8C:DD:7B:DA:1B  |  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    |  ca-ab-sub-46
```

Query 1: I need to graph the average temperature across all locations on the hour for the last 24 hours.

Query 2: I also need to graph the average temperature per location on the hour for the last 24 hours.

So far I can get the number of temperature readings averaged per hour using:

```
SELECT HOUR(`updated`), COUNT(*), ROUND(AVG(`temp`))
FROM `sensor_temps`
WHERE `updated` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY HOUR(`updated`)
ORDER BY HOUR(`updated`)
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

For query 2 I am planning on doing something like the following:

```
SELECT HOUR(`updated`), COUNT(*), ROUND(AVG(`temp`))
FROM `sensor_temps`
WHERE `updated` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND `location_id` = `ca-ab-sub-46`
GROUP BY HOUR(`updated`)
ORDER BY HOUR(`updated`)
```

I am not sure how I can join the sensor table in a way that will be efficient with more data. Looking for ways to optimize since I am expecting 10's of millions of records once the system is scaled out.

Comment: Your "question" has two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the data will be written once and read many times.Looking at the use case your 
system might scale with increase in the number of sensors.So the table design and datamodel should consider that into account at the very first place. Below are my comments and recommendation.

Assumptions :Data once inserted is unchanged.i.e. write once ready many.

Recommendation in general for Datamodel :

1. Create two new tables to store the aggregated value from query 1 and query 2.Purpose is to store aggregated data that can be read by GUI pretty quickly rather than doing an 
   aggregation real-time.The table should have all columns from respective select queries(Query 1 and Query 2).
2. Two tables has to be populated by end of day(after 00:00 nextday) using a scheduled task. Basically an insert script to `insert into newtablequery1 select .. from query1`.Likewise insert script is required for query 2.
3. GUI to fetch data from these new tables for dates other than current day.This will be awesome fast.
4. Now for current date we have to rely on the queries provided(Suggestion to improve the queries can be found bit below in the thread).This suggestions still holds good when 1,2 and 3 are not a viable.Below are few improvements,

   - Add non-unique index sensor_temps on updated column.
   - Range partition by month Year for faster data retrieval with growing data.This is not essential but will value maybe after couple of years.
   - Adding unique index on location_id will improve query 2.
   - sensors.id should be primary key and hence will be indexed by default.

Query 1 : Minor change in query to perform sorting from the inline view,implementing the indexes mentioned above should be good enough.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT HOUR(`updated`) AS hr, COUNT(*) as cnt , ROUND(AVG(`temp`)) as avgtemp
FROM `sensor_temps`
WHERE `updated` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY HOUR(`updated`)) sensor_temps_avg
ORDER BY hr
```

Query 2 :Modified the query to create an inline view from sensor_temps with aggregate and then join with 
sensors, this would reduce the hash table formed by the join.

```
select id,location_id,hr,cnt,avgtemp
from sensors,
(SELECT id,HOUR(`updated`) as hr, COUNT(*) as cnt, ROUND(AVG(`temp`)) as avgtemp
FROM `sensor_temps`
WHERE `updated` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
GROUP BY HOUR(`updated`)) sensor_temps_avg
where sensors.id = sensor_temps_avg.id
AND `location_id` = `ca-ab-sub-46`
ORDER BY HR
```

If you have a DBA managing the Database i would definitely recommend to take the case with them,nevertheless these recommendation should help.